# adding parameters to execvp from char array in c

Tags: c, linux, execvp

I have an array of strings containing the input parameters for `execvp`. How can I turn it into an array of string pointers for `execvp`?

For command with one argument, two strings are present:

```
char param[4][10] = ["wc","file.txt"]
```

And with two arguments:

```
char param[4][10] = ["cp","file1.txt","file2.txt"]
```

If I know the number of arguments in advance, I can simply write

```
char *arg[]={param[0],param[1],NULL} 
execvp(arg[0],arg);
```

or

```
char *arg[]={param[0],param[1], param[2], NULL} 
execvp(arg[0],arg);
```

respectively.

But what can I do when I don’t know the number of arguments?

I tried looping

```
int count =4;
char* arg[count];
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    strcpy(exe[i],param[i]);
    printf("%s\n",exe[i]);
}
strcpy(exe[count],'\0');
```

but that gave me segfaults.

Comment: You're writing past the allocated `array`. `array[count]` is not in an array whose size is `count`. You cannot `strcpy` to random uninitialized pointers; and you need not. The last entry in the arguments must be a null pointer.

Comment: @Antti, Sorry for the confusion. My param array is of size 4, whose index is 3. thats why.

Comment: you're writing to `arg[3]`, where `arg` is a variable-length-array with 3 elements.

Answer (score 3):

The arg list to `execvp()` needs to be the length of your `param` list plus one (null terminator).  So if `param` is an array of C strings of length N:

```
char** arg = malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(char*));
if (arg == NULL) {
    abort();
}
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < N; ++ii) {
    arg[ii] = param[ii];
}
arg[N] = NULL;
```

Now you can call:

```
execvp(arg[0], arg);
```

Comment: Thanks @John Zwinck for the quick reply. I ran into another problem though. The code char**   arg = malloc((N + 1) * sizeof(char*)); shows  invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’. This is probably because I am using g++. How can I make it run with g++, any idea?

Comment: @SafwanUllKarim: add `(char**)` in front of `malloc()` to compile as C++.

Comment: If you're using C++, you probably want to use `new char*[N+1]` instead of `malloc()`.

Comment: @TobySpeight: The OP tagged the question as C.  As for why they are compiling with g++, I'm not going to go there.

Comment: @John - You're absolutely right to answer a [tag:c] question in C!